# White rectangle on the right top of profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, top-bar

I see a white rectangle on the right top of [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current):

> [image: rectangle]

Currently I’m using Chrome on iPad.

Same behavior is observing for any other page when responsiveness is disabled.

Comment: I saw this yesterday with latest Firefox on MacOS High Sierra. At the time, I assumed it was due to me changing displays and resolutions. Appeared on any window more than 1080px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fixed now:

> [image: no white at the corner]