# Show “edited” in one line with “posted” if possible in responsive design

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, responsive-design

I just noticed on my iPad, that “edited” block is [displayed above the “posted” block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311364/339911) in case of responsive design:

> [image: responsive]

In old (normal) style both items are displayed in single line:

> [image: single line]

As you could see there is a lot of free space (below the “share/edit/etc” links) to show items in single line even in case of responsive design. Could it please be fixed/implemented?